# What are the differences between foward air controllers in US military?

Tags: military, us-air-force

US Military has forward air controllers that join the forces on the front line and help them communicate with aircraft on the battelfield.

I found several Wikipedia articles describing such position, but can't understand what are the differences between them.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tactical_Air_Control_Party

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_air_control

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_terminal_attack_controller

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Air_Force_Combat_Control_Team

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Air_Force_Tactical_Air_Control_Party

Comment: As the descriptions in the Wikipedia articles mention, different branches and countries have different definitions. To make things more complicated meanings of the terms are overlapping and have changed over time. Most differences are in actual privileges of that role, but that also changes. From my point of view the most used term is JTAC nowadays.